# Create multiple vectors for separate user's responses to separate questions

Tags: r

I have user data from between 1 and 20 multiple-response questions (i.e., for each question the user actually completed they could check off multiple responses, up to 44). Here's a subset of the data (representing 3 multiple-response questions with 5 response options on each):

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, q1.response1 = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), 
    q1.response2 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), q1.response3 = c(NA, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA), q1.response4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), q1.response5 = c(NA, 
    1L, 1L, NA, NA), q2.response1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q2.response2 = c(1L, 
    NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), q2.response3 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), q2.response4 = c(1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1L), q2.response5 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response1 = c(1L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q3.response3 = c(1L, 
    NA, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response4 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q3.response5 = c(1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "q1.response1", "q1.response2", 
"q1.response3", "q1.response4", "q1.response5", "q2.response1", 
"q2.response2", "q2.response3", "q2.response4", "q2.response5", 
"q3.response1", "q3.response2", "q3.response3", "q3.response4", 
"q3.response5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

A "1" indicates that they checked off that option; NA indicates that they did not.

What I want is to create a vector for each question, where the vector will contain just the IDs of the responses the user checked off. So, the sample data provided here should produce 13 vectors (users 1,2,4 gave responses to all 3 questions, so 3x3=9 vectors, while users 3 and 5 only gave responses to questions 1 and 2, so 2x2=4 vectors), and the vectors (which I want to be named user1q1, user1q2, user1q3, user2q1, and so on) should look like this:

```
> user1q1
[1] 1 4
# since in questions 1, user 1 only checked off response options 1 and 4, and the other 3 responses are NA

> user1q2
[1] 2 4

> user1q3
[1] 1 3 4 5

> user2q1
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

...and so on. I've tried doing this by creating empty vectors and appending to them using loops, but (1) I can't get the code to work and (2) I've been told to try to avoid loops if possible, but I'm not sure how in this case. I'm happy to provide what I've tried (with the loops) if it would help, but I think there's too many things wrong with it for it to be worth posting. Any help would be amazingly appreciated!

Comment: All users don't have the same number of questions? Also, is it like different questions have differing number of responses?

Comment: Users did not all answer the same number of questions; they could choose how many of the total number of questions they wanted to answer. All questions have the same number of response options, and users could choose as few or as many response options as they wanted. Does that make sense?

Comment: No my question concerned about the structure of data. I  have added a solution for your sample data-set. You can customize it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution for your example case. You can customize it as per your requirement.

```
possibleResponses <- 5
numberOfQuestions <- 3
d2 <- apply(df, 1, function(userData) {
  responseData <- matrix(userData[-1], nrow = numberOfQuestions, byrow = T)
  structure(sapply(1:nrow(responseData), function(Qn) {
    which(!is.na(responseData[Qn, ]))
  }), names = paste0("user", userData[1], "q", 1:nrow(responseData)))
})

d3 <- do.call(c, d2)
```

`d3` will contain the output vectors.

Comment: @abclist19, You can modify the `possibleResponses` & `numberOfQuestions` variables according to your data-set. These are the number of responses per question and the number of questions per user respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it with the exact sample data I provided in my question (which I called `userData`), and I got this error: `Error in apply(df, 1, function(userData) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: @abclist19, But you call your data `df` (not `userData`) in your question. And I have tested the solution, it works for the sample data `df` you have posted in your question.

Comment: You're absolutely right; silly mistake on my part. The code works perfectly for both the sample data and my complete data set.

Answer (score 1):

This might help too:

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- df[,2:6]
df2 <- df[,7:11]
df3 <- df[,12:16]
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

which.col <- function(v, target=1, opposite=FALSE) {
  if (opposite == FALSE) {
    index <- which(v==target)
  } else {
    index <- which(!v==target)
  }
  return(names(v)[index])
}

user <- function(userid, question) {
  l <-  which.col(dfs[[question]][userid,])
  return(as.numeric(str_extract(l, ".$")))
}

user(1,1)
[1] 1 4

user(1,2)
[1] 2 4

user(1,3)
[1] 1 3 4 5
```

## Explanation

I broke the data frame into 3 pieces. I then created a function that looks for the column names of vectors that satisfy a value. Then I create a function called `user` that allows you to enter an id and question to get a vector of their responses.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be really close; it works great with my sample data, but when I apply it to my full data set and try the `user` function, I get `> user(2,1)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In user(2, 1) : NAs introduced by coercion`. The number of placeholders is correct (i.e., user(2,1) should have 5 numbers), but they all come out as NA. Any idea why this might be happening? The full data set is in the same format as the sample data (all 1s and NAs).

Comment: The only way to tell is to see some of your data. I also added `library(stringr)` to my answer.